# ¿como puedo cambiar la ruta de acceso de algún elemento en visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

como cambiar la ruta de acceso de un elemento de un proyecto de visual studio
quiero cambiar esta ruta[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita el archivo del proyecto  con algún editor de texto

Comment: moverlo en la solucion no funciono porque?

Comment: Estas marcando un archivo generado por el editor, no se puede cambiar la ruta a menos que se regenere y lo hara en la misma carpeta del proyecto. Si quieres puede agregar un resx adicional al proyecto para sortar idioma, pero no el resx asociado al form, porque no eres tu quien genera ese archivo es el editor

Answer (score -1):

Yo lo que haría:

1. Hacer hacer una copia de ese archivo en el sitio que quieras
2. Quitar ese archivo. Boton derecho, QUITAR.
3. Boton derecho, AGREGAR, ELEMENTO EXISTENTE. Busca la copia del archivo donde has dejado en el paso 1.

Espero que te sirva.